# Intersperse strings among variables in a table

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation

How can I intersperse strings among variables to create a table with labels for each entry. A simple example of what I tried to do would be a table of the value of a function $f(x)$ and the value of $x$. For example:

```
Table[{"x=" x, "f[x]=" f}, {x, 0, 1, .1}] // TableForm
```

What I would like to obtain:

```
x=0   f=f[0]
x=0.1 f=f[0.1]
x=0.2 f=f[0.2]
...
```

But, of course, my code didn't produce that.

Comment: `Table[StringTemplate["x=`` f[x]=f[``]"][x, x], {x, 0, 1, .1}] // TableForm` You can also use `StringJoin` if you first apply `ToString` to the numeric values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

m_goldberg's answer is good for small outputs, but you have to consider that internally, Mathematica will create very complex front end structures to display lots of "boxes" - strings mixed with integers, formatted, each to have their paddings and frames and margins, etc. In a large enough output or long enough notebook, this can really add up. Alternatively, use `ToString` to convert numbers to strings (use `NumberForm` and others to format the number, if you'd like, and `IntegerString` to convert to other systems, such as Binary, or Roman numerals, etc). Use `<>` instead of `+` to join strings.

```
Table[{"x="<>ToString[x], "f[x]="<>ToString[f[x]]}, {x, 0, 1, .1}] // TableForm
```

...produces the output you want

Comment: Thanks for the simple and effective solution!

Answer (score 1):

[`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) is your friend is a situation like this.

```
Table[{Row[{"x = ", x}], Row[{"f = f[", x, "]"}]}, {x, 0, 1, .1}] // TableForm
```

[image: table]

Comment: Great answer! While it does the trick, I found @Gregory 's answer simpler to implement.
Thanks!